# iPad/iPhone book view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

How can I create a book view for iPhone/iPad? I have PDFs and I must create a module that displays a PDF as a book so you can turn pages. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the following Github project.

https://github.com/ansani/leaves

> An iBooks-like page-turning interface
>   for iPhone and iPad apps using only
>   public APIs.